# Can we implement AMP-HTML on a Gatsby.js app?

Tags: reactjs, amp-html, gatsby

I am fairly new to AMP and have been asked to develop GatsbyJS website using AMP-HTML. I have also read that about the Gatsby-Plugin-AMP, it stats there may be situations where an image, iframe or some other element can’t be modified.  But I am not sure which can or cannot be modified and if the bogs down our flexibility.

And if possible can you share some links for that. Any help is welcome

Comment: Hey, did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

I’m the author of that plugin. That warning is just pointing out that the plugin can’t anticipate every use case for a standard Gatsby-rendered page. There may also be things that are added by other plugins that can make your page not be validated. So, you *may* need to create a separate template that allows your page to be AMP-compatible. Have you tried it and found that it didn’t meet your needs?

If so, I’d love to find out why that is and hopefully fix it! The only way to make the plugin work for more use cases than mine specifically is to get feedback from users like you.

Comment: i used the same plugin, but why does it only run in production, when i try locally, it doesnt give me the log powered by amp